# How to check firewall is enabled for virtual network using azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network

I want to check firewall status (enabled/ disabled) for a virtual network using azure cli.

can I consider if I have **AzureFirewallSubnet** in the subnet list of the particular virtual network then the firewall is enabled for the virtual network?

Answer (score 1):

There are many CLI commands which you can use to get Firewall configurations. One of them is:

```
az network firewall list [--resource-group]
```

**This will list all the Firewalls in a RG.**

*Check out the [complete list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-firewall/network/firewall?view=azure-cli-latest) of Firewall CLI commands and you can use any ***List*** command to check if Firewall exists or not.*